# Selecting latest conversations from table containing private messages

Tags: mysql, group-by

I have a table containing personal messages from one user to another.

Here is the table structure:

```
mysql> describe pms;
+---------+--------------+------+-----+---------+----------------+
| Field   | Type         | Null | Key | Default | Extra          |
+---------+--------------+------+-----+---------+----------------+
| id      | int(11)      | NO   | PRI | NULL    | auto_increment |
| time    | datetime     | NO   |     | NULL    |                |
| from    | int(11)      | NO   |     | NULL    |                |
| from_ip | int(11)      | NO   |     | NULL    |                |
| to      | int(11)      | NO   |     | NULL    |                |
| message | varchar(255) | NO   |     | NULL    |                |
| read    | tinyint(4)   | NO   |     | 0       |                |
+---------+--------------+------+-----+---------+----------------+
```

I am creating a view which shows 10 latest conversations of a particular user id. As I want to find conversations, I thought of using GROUP BY `from`, `to`. This, however, returned duplicate rows (both from this user and to this user), and I also noticed that ordering does not work as it should.

In order to be able to properly order the results and thus select the 10 latest conversations, the groups should contain the latest row of the group instead of the first.

Here is the query I tried:

```
SELECT * 
FROM  `pms` 
WHERE  `from` = 1
OR  `to` = 1
GROUP BY  `from` ,  `to` 
ORDER BY  `id` DESC 
LIMIT 10
```

Which gives the wrong row from the group, and therefore ordering by id (or time) gives a wrong order.

Any ideas how I could get it working?

Comment: Possible duplicate: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7033789/mysql-how-to-get-non-aggregate-columns-from-a-table-based-on-an-aggregate-colu

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This assumes that a conversation is defined by the from-to pair in either order, and that the latest conversation has the largest id:

```
SELECT least(`from`,  `to`), greatest(`from`, `to`)
FROM  `pms` 
WHERE  `from` = 1 OR  `to` = 1
GROUP BY  least(`from`,  `to`), greatest(`from`, `to`)
ORDER BY max( `id`) DESC 
LIMIT 10
```